# Jquery: Open a html window in popup jquery

Tags: jquery, html, authentication, popupwindow

I). I was trying to open a new html page in popup window. Popup window is for login into database I tried using a sample [Popup Sample](http://vasplus.info/tutorial.php?id=99&?Yeah_man&_expid=/VXpoc01YRjNjakJqUTNCUGFXWkVURk5qTVhseVVFSXhZMkpWUmtGQkpUTkVKVE5F/2014/mQu5D1bwvu#.U1E1aFdgw-U) but it didn't word. Below is my code which I was trying:

**Menu.html**

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <a href="vpb_show_login_box()" class="vpb_general_button">Login</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Changes in jquery:**

```
function vpb_show_login_box()
{
    $("#vpb_pop_up_background").css({
        "opacity": "0.4"
    });
    $("#vpb_pop_up_background").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#vpb_login_pop_up_box").fadeIn('fast');
    $("#vpb_login_pop_up_box").load("login.html");
    window.scroll(0,0);
}
```

May I know what mistake I am doing?

II). Also I have another question. I have two different database. One Database consisting client details and another client's project. If my menu is like below:

**Menu.html**

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <a href="vpb_show_login_box()" class="vpb_general_button">Client Detail</a>
        <a href="vpb_show_login_box()" class="vpb_general_button">Client Project</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Question: How can I use same login page but it adds on extra login requirements. i.e.

For *Client Detail* (Login)

Username and Passowrd requirement to login

For *Client Project*

Username, Passowrd and Department requirement to login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have jQuery available anyway why not make full use of it?

You can add a `click` event in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/click/) like this:

```
$('.vpb_general_button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    vpb_show_login_box($(this).data('popup-type'));
});
```

In your HTML add a `data-attribute` to specify the popup type and remove the `onclick` attribute and replace the `href` value with a `#`:

```
...
<td>
    <a href="#" data-popup-type="detail" class="vpb_general_button">Client Detail</a>
    <a href="#" data-popup-type="project" class="vpb_general_button">Client Project</a>
</td>
...
```

In your `vpb_show_login_box` function handle the different popup types. For example:

```
function vpb_show_login_box(popupType) // add popupType here
{ 
    ...
    if (popupType === 'detail') {
        $("#vpb_login_pop_up_box").load("login_detail.html");
    }
    if (popupType === 'project') {
        $("#vpb_login_pop_up_box").load("login_project.html");
    }
    ...
}
```

**Update after comment**

If you need to use the `login.html` for the different popups you can add the parameter to the URL. But you need to handle the popupType paramater in your `login.html` (here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979995/3351720)).

```
function vpb_show_login_box(popupType) // add popupType here
{ 
    ...
    $("#vpb_login_pop_up_box").load("login.html?popupType=" + popupType);
    ...
}
```

**Update 2**

With callback function:

```
function vpb_show_login_box(popupType)
{ 
    ...
    $("#vpb_login_pop_up_box").load("login.html", function() {
        if (popupType === 'detail') {
            $('.detail-container').show();
        }

        if (popupType === 'project') {
            $('.project-container').show();
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: No you didn't understood I want is one login.html page with two different login types. That is the requirement which I have create. But i'll also try to check if you give code is working or not.

Comment: Can I do it this way
    
if (popupType === 'project') {
        $("#vpb_pop_up_background").css({ "opacity": "0.4" });
        $("#vpb_pop_up_background").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#vpb_login_pop_up_box").fadeIn('fast');
        load.department = visible.true; //Textbox visible to true (code is wrong)
        $("#vpb_login_pop_up_box").load("login.html");
        
    }

Comment: No you can't, you don't have control over the `login.html` yet. You can however add a `callback` to your `load()` function and handle it then. See [jQuery load documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `href` to `onclick`.

```
<a onclick="vpb_show_login_box()" href="javascript:;" class="vpb_general_button">Login</a>
```

Or prefix `javascript:` before calling it in `href`